# Variables in history?

Tags: logs, command-history

Is it possible to include environment variables in the history output.

Something along the lines of:

```
%T %F $SUDO_USER $HISTORY_COMMAND
1 2015-01-01 00:00:00 USER123 echo 123
```

Reason being we have a shared user on our servers and would like to know which individuals are executing which commands when they log on as that user.

I've had a Google around and found very few variables to configure history.

I'm currently formatting the timestamp with `HISTTIMESTAMP='%T %F '` it's the `$SUDO_USER` part I'm stuck with.

Comment: If you want accounting, don't use a shared account. Otherwise it's a lost cause.

Comment: A user can change variable, so could work around what you are doing. You need proper secure account logging.

Comment: I'm not trying to catch people out, it's so we can see what we're doing individually. Also I can't change this, it's not my decision I'm just trying to find the best way to work with it as it's a user we have to sudo to frequently.